# Broken USB stick keeps disappearing, preventing any repair operations

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive

I am trying to fix a broken USB pendrive. This is a new USB pendrive, which does not work properly anymore after a colleague tried to encrypt it. I unfortunately do not know how the encryption was botched, but I assume that vital data (partition table or something similar) was mangled in the process.

---

When I plug it in, it is found by the system and shows up in the output of `lsusb` and `lsblk`.

However, when I subsequently try to run `dd` or `badblocks` or `mkfs` to do something, all these commands eventually fail due to an I/O error. When this happened, the pendrive also doesn't show up in the output of `lsusb` or `lsblk`.
So, I assume that the pendrive gets disconnected by the OS somehow in the process.

What can I do to keep the thing connected?

`dmesg` has this to say:

```
330181.324715] usb 4-4.3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[2330181.352153] usb 4-4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 0.02
[2330181.352157] usb 4-4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2330181.352159] usb 4-4.3: Product: Intenso Speed Line  
[2330181.352161] usb 4-4.3: Manufacturer: ALCOR          
[2330181.352163] usb 4-4.3: SerialNumber: 09104353
[2330181.355880] usb-storage 4-4.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[2330181.356110] scsi host9: usb-storage 4-4.3:1.0
[2330182.464306] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  Speed Line       8.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[2330182.464755] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[2330182.465486] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] 250183680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[2330182.465705] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[2330182.465709] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[2330182.465901] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[2330182.487834] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
[2330219.614115] usb 4-4.3: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[2330224.734155] usb 4-4.3: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[2330229.854129] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330235.230139] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330235.438099] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[2330240.862114] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330246.238112] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330246.446069] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[2330251.870138] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330257.246135] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330257.454081] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[2330262.878115] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330268.254073] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330268.462106] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[2330268.462229] usb 4-4.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[2330268.462238] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[2330268.462244] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e e9 7f f9 00 00 01 00
[2330268.462248] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 250183673 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[2330268.462344] sd 9:0:0:0: tag#0 timing out command, waited 60s
[2330268.462371] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 250183672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[2330268.462376] Buffer I/O error on dev sdg, logical block 31272959, async page read
[2330273.886115] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330279.262066] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330279.470087] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 5, error -62
[2330284.894048] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330290.270122] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330290.478027] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[2330290.478068] usb 4-4-port3: attempt power cycle
[2330295.902131] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330301.278118] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330301.486104] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 7, error -62
[2330306.910107] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330312.286095] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[2330312.494098] usb 4-4.3: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[2330312.494184] usb 4-4-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Answer (score 0):

> *When I subsequently try to run `dd` or `badblocks` or `mkfs` [...] these commands eventually fail due to an I/O error. [...] I assume that the pendrive gets disconnected by the OS somehow in the process. [...] What can I do to keep the thing connected?*

Don't write to it. You've already said it's broken, so do what you can to read data from it, but avoid any more writes. If you have a write-protect switch on the device, turn it on.

When you've recovered what you can, physically destroy the device (so any remaining data is irretrievable) and replace it.

Comment: There is no data on it. A colleague botched encrypting this new pendrive. What I want to achieve is to make it usable again.

Comment: I should have clarified my situation earlier, sorry for that. Otherwise, simply destroying the pendrive would be proper advice.

Comment: It's faulty, which is why it's failing when you try to write to it